# Create Event From .Net Library Manually To Talk To MQ

Tags: c#, msmq

The MessageQueue object in .Net is used to talk to MSMQ messages. I am asked to now talk to MQ instead. I would like to reuse the code I have shown below to listen to messages. In order to do that I think I will need to manually create a new object similar to the MessageQueue object.

How do I create the ReceiveCompleted Event and the BeginRecieve and EndRecieve Methods so I can talk to MQ? Or can I somehow use MQ with the MessageQueue object given by .Net?

```
private MessageQueue _OperationMessageQueue;
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            OperationMessageQueue.BeginReceive();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            OperationMessageQueue.ReceiveCompleted -= Mq_ReceiveCompleted;
            OperationMessageQueue.Dispose();
        }

  protected MessageQueue OperationMessageQueue
        {
            get
            {
                if (_OperationMessageQueue == null)
                {
                    _OperationMessageQueue = new MessageQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OperationMessageQueuePath"]);
                    _OperationMessageQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(RequestContainer) });
                    _OperationMessageQueue.ReceiveCompleted += Mq_ReceiveCompleted;
                }
                return _OperationMessageQueue;
            }
        }

        private void Mq_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        //a message has been received
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean [IBM MQ](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ibm-mq)?

Comment: The MessageQueue object is specifically for MSMQ. You will need an IBM MQ client library.